# All css/img files route to the site's homepage

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I have pulled a Laravel application from a remote server and trying to set up a local version.

I copied all the files and database, and managed to server up the local application. All the routes seems to work, except for one big problem - all the assets from the `public` folder route to the site's homepage!

For, example, I have an image included like so:

```
<img src="{{ asset('img/main-logo.png') }}" />
```

On the production server, this displays the image, with the source URL `https://www.example.com/img/main-logo.png` and this works correctly.

On my local server, the image source turns out to be `http://localhost:8005/img/main-logo.png`, which should be correct, but it doesn't show the image. When I try to open this URL in the browser, instead of showing the image it opens the site homepage!

I have the server.php file in the root folder, `index.php` in `public`, and the following `.htaccess` in my `public` folder (copied from the production server):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    # Force compression for mangled headers.
    # https://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/pushing-beyond-gzipping-25601.html

    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
            RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
     <filesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|webp|js|ico)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2628000, public"
     </filesMatch>
    </IfModule>

    # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    # Map certain file types to the specified encoding type in order to
    # make Apache serve them with the appropriate `Content-Encoding` HTTP
    # response header (this will NOT make Apache compress them!).

    # If the following file types wouldn't be served without the appropriate
    # `Content-Enable` HTTP response header, client applications (e.g.:
    # browsers) wouldn't know that they first need to uncompress the response,
    # and thus, wouldn't be able to understand the content.

    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#addencoding

    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        AddEncoding gzip              svgz
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE "application/atom+xml" \
                                      "application/javascript" \
                                      "application/json" \
                                      "application/ld+json" \
                                      "application/manifest+json" \
                                      "application/rdf+xml" \
                                      "application/rss+xml" \
                                      "application/schema+json" \
                                      "application/vnd.geo+json" \
                                      "application/vnd.ms-fontobject" \
                                      "application/x-font-ttf" \
                                      "application/x-web-app-manifest+json" \
                                      "application/xhtml+xml" \
                                      "application/xml" \
                                      "font/opentype" \
                                      "image/svg+xml" \
                                      "image/x-icon" \
                                      "text/cache-manifest" \
                                      "text/css" \
                                      "text/html" \
                                      "text/javascript" \
                                      "text/plain" \
                                      "text/vtt" \
                                      "text/x-component" \
                                      "text/xml"
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots.php

    # rewrite non www to www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost:8005 [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:8005/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # redir for last / in url
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =GET
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ /$1$2 [NC,L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

So it's the same .htaccess, same routes, yet the assets that load on the production server don't load locally. Anyone know why that may be and how to fix it?

I have tried adding 'public/' to the asset URLs, tried absolute/relative paths instead too, nothing works.

EDIT: in the meanwhile I have tried editing .htaccess in various ways, and even removing it completely, and nothing changed in the way the website handles the routing for public assets.

EDIT #2: while `http://localhost:8005/img/main-logo.png` loads the site's homepage, `http://localhost:8005/public/img/main-logo.png` gives a 404 error

EDIT #3: when I load `http://localhost:8005/img/main-logo.png` it shows this under 'routing':

[image]

Comment: have you tried my solution?

Comment: check your env file there must be a app url which you didn't change i think .

Comment: did you try `php artisan storage:link`? Maybe the assets are served from the storage folder, not the assets directory itself.

Comment: @jovan please provide .env file

Comment: What is the absolute filesystem path to your images? What is the `DocumentRoot`? There's something missing from your config... if your application is installed in the `/public` subdirectory off the root directory (document root?) and the `/public` subdirectory is not included in the URL-path, then you need _something_ that rewrites the request to the `/public` subdirectory - there is nothing in what you've posted that does this?

Answer (score 1):

i had a same problem and i fixed it. try this.
I changed **/vendor/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php**  asset() function as follows:

```
function asset($path, $secure = null)
{
    return app('url')->asset("public/".$path, $secure);
}
```

Hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

I am really unsure why it would be working on the server and not on local, unless there are some settings/toolings on the server that are not the same as on your local... Maybe it is in front of a CDN? That would prevent the requests to even hit the server and get the files served from the service instead... Anyways, here's how I would tackle this problem:

```
RewriteRule     ^img/(.*) path/to/public/$1 [L]
# Handle Front Controller...
# ...
```

This added line will rewrite all that starts with img to your public directory that way the file will get served directly. You'd need to change the rule to accomodate for any other static assets, like you might need to do it for your javascript and css files?

There is also a possibility to only rewrite if the target file exists, but for my part, I prefer giving out a 404 error rather than landing the user to the homepage.

EDIT: Note that this answer is using my global htaccess knowledge. I do not know Laravel much and it might handle static assets from its PHP... But my solution should work no matter the framework.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. I have also tried various absolute paths, with or without the 'public/' part of the URL, and still the same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your home directory .htaccess file as below and try. It will work in server as well as in your local. Make sure you take a backup of your original htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
    RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: That doesn't change anything, sorry.

Comment: Have you copied your index.php from public to home? can you tell me your local web server name please? xampp/wampp?

Comment: No, I haven't, and I shouldn't need to. I don't want my local setup different from the production setup. All my applications run with server.php in the home folder and index.php in the public folder. It's xampp.

Comment: Hi This issue is coming bcz of virtual host issue. I'll post my solution as new command please follow that.

Comment: @jovan, check my solution [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53777674/all-css-img-files-route-to-the-sites-homepage/53812558#53812558

Answer (score 0):

Your server using apache's custom modules like `deflate, gzip` but may be these has not on your local machine.

First, can you try use following codes in your `.htaccess` file that default content of laravel.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

If above codes works currectly, you can try install these custom module.

Comment: I wrote same time. :) Did you try test on your Browser's Incognito Window after changed .htaccces file? Sometimes it cached on browsers.

Comment: I tried clearing cache and even different browsers, no change.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code into your virtual host file under apache folder C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf.

```
<VirtualHost *:8005>
  ServerName my-app.local
  DocumentRoot "C:/XAMPP/htdocs/laravel/public"
  <Directory "C:/XAMPP/htdocs/laravel/public">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

NOTE: Replace `laravel` with your `project folder` name.

After this edit your host file from `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and add below line

```
127.0.0.1 my-app.local
```

and finally restart you apache and after restart try to access your application using http://my-app.local

Note: DONT FORGET TO REMOVE ALL YOUR CHANGES FROM HTACCESS FILE

Hope it will work